# XmlPullParser getting all child values

Tags: android, xmlpullparser

How can I get child xml values  ?

I mean : If `xml.getName() = Section` give me its  Sub values. I think I must use a while loop in it but I couldnt achieve it !

OR is it possible to get parent value ?

```
<Top name="Top category">

  <Section name="Sub category 1">
     <Sub note="text" />
     <Sub note="text" />
  </Section>

<Section name="Sub category 2">
     <Sub note="text" />
     <Sub note="text" />
  </Section>

</Top>
```

...

```
  while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

 if ((eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) &&(_xml.getName().equals("Section"))){
                    String _Section = _xml.getAttributeValue(null, "name");

// take its Sub note values


   }    

 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with pull parsers you have to create an object such that it can be accessed when you run into a subelement of that object. For example in this case whenever you run into a START_TAG for a Section, create a Section object and save it in a variable outside of the method scope. Then if you find another START_TAG Sub *and* the Section is not null,it means you're in a section and you need to add a sub section. Once you find an END_TAG for Section then add the current Section object to a list and then set that variable you had to `null`.

Comment: Is it possible to use `getDepth()` . If I use `_xml.getDepth()-1` , I think it will give me depth of parent so is it possible to get values of parent depth ?

Comment: Urrr.. what do you need the depth for?

Comment: I want to get parent node value while getting sub nodes if its possible.

Comment: Or are there any example use of your method?

Comment: Can you provide some snippet so we can easily understand.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest using a good de-serialization library like AQuery - https://code.google.com/p/android-query/

I'm no way associated with the project, but seems it can solve your task in hand much more efficiently and robustly